# Why are my columns showing up as NaN when they are not empty?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to use pandas to create a data frame from a .csv file I have downloaded. Every time I try to make a predictors data frame, it empties one of the columns I am looking for. I downloaded the .csv file from here: https://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/eagan/class/igr204/datasets
It is the fourth file down titled "film.csv"

I have done this in the following way before with a different dataset and it worked flawlessly. This time my data is being deleted and I cannot figure out why.

```py
import pandas as pd

file=pd.read_csv('film.csv',sep=';',encoding="ISO 8859-1")
#print(file)
df=pd.DataFrame(file)

df=df.dropna(axis=0,how='any')

predictors=pd.DataFrame(df.Director,df.Length)
#prints directors as NaN
print(predictors)

#prints both columns fully
print(df.Director)
print(df.Length)
```

Printing the predictors data frame above prints out the Length column correctly, but the Director column with all files as NaN. All I want is a data frame of the two columns Director and Length. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Edit:

These are the first 10 lines of the csv file.

```
     Year;Length;Title;Subject;Actor;Actress;Director;Popularity;Awards
INT;INT;STRING;CAT;CAT;CAT;CAT;INT;BOOL;STRING
1990;111;Tie Me Up! Tie Me Down!;Comedy;Banderas, Antonio;Abril, 
Victoria;Almodóvar, Pedro;68;No
1991;113;High Heels;Comedy;Bosé, Miguel;Abril, Victoria;Almodóvar, 
Pedro;68;No
1983;104;Dead Zone, The;Horror;Walken, Christopher;Adams, 
Brooke;Cronenberg, David;79;No
1979;122;Cuba;Action;Connery, Sean;Adams, Brooke;Lester, Richard;6;No
1978;94;Days of Heaven;Drama;Gere, Richard;Adams, Brooke;Malick, 
Terrence;14;No
1983;140;Octopussy;Action;Moore, Roger;Adams, Maud;Glen, John;68;No
1984;101;Target Eagle;Action;Connors, Chuck;Adams, Maud;Loma, José 
Antonio de la;14;No
1989;99;American Angels: Baptism of Blood, The;Drama;Bergen, Robert 
D.;Adams, Trudy;Sebastian, Beverly;28;No
```

Comment: Can you add a few lines of the csv data - enough to reproduce/illustrate the problem? Copy the data as text paste it into your question and format as code.  Please read [mcve].

Comment: @wwii I made the edits, thank you.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. I tried your code, and seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line `predictors=pd.DataFrame(df.Director,df.Length)`

TO create a new dataframe from old, use something like:

`predictors=df[['Director', 'Length']].copy()`

Comment: THANK YOU!! I have been trying to figure this out all day and just confusing myself more. This worked, thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help. I will put some more details in the answer later. Apologize for the terseness.